# Maximum Peers Reached, Connection To Private Node Dropped

Tags: node, private-mode, connections

At 99 peers, my node 7a877820 (2019-12-11 15:02:03 +0100) starts getting

```
Dec 17 06:48:30 - p2p.connection-pool: Swap to x.x.x.x.:9732 failed: Error:
Dec 17 06:48:30 - p2p.connection-pool:           Too many connections.
```

But config does not have a max of 100 specified:

```
{ "rpc": { "listen-addrs": [ "127.0.0.1:8732" ] },
  "p2p":
    { "bootstrap-peers":
        [ "boot.tzbeta.net", "dubnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
          "franodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "sinnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
          "nrtnodes.tzbeta.net:9732", "pdxnodes.tzbeta.net:9732",
          "a.b.c.d:9732" ], "listen-addr": "0.0.0.0:9732",
      "limits":
        { "connection-timeout": 10, "min-connections": 15,
          "max_known_points": [ 240, 180 ],
          "max_known_peer_ids": [ 240, 180 ] } },
  "log": { "output": "/home/tezos/.tezos-node/tezos-node.log" },
  "shell":
    { "chain_validator": { "bootstrap_threshold": 2 },
      "history_mode": "archive" } }
```

I find 100 peers enough, but **why does it consider too many peers at 100 if the config has no such limit? Is 100 the default max?**

More importantly, it disconnects my private node, `a.b.c.d:9732`. The private node is set to run on cron `tezos-admin-client trust peer id12345abcde`, where `id12345abcde` is the id of public node with 100 connections. I don't think `trust peer` means stay connected to this peer, simply tells the private node to accept connections from node id `id12345abcde`, but the bottom line is: **how do I ensure that the public node doesn't drop the connection to the private node when it reaches max connected nodes?**

Comment: Please go upvote and comment on these P2P layer issues. Doesn't look like you are the only one. IMHO, a trusted peer should always be maintained by the node.

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/367

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/278

Comment: Done for 367 and 278. I guess for now I have to schedule restarts for the public node when a script detects it is not connected to the private peer...

Comment: @utdrmac i have a mitigation in place. oh well.

Answer (score 1):

If you started your private node with eg.

```
[...] --net-addr 127.0.0.1:9876 [...]
```

add the following peer to the public node so that it `trusts` the private node:

```
[...] --peer 127.0.0.1:9876 [...]
```

The function that kills some connections when there are too many does not kill connections that are both in `private mode and trusted`.

See:

https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_p2p/p2p_maintenance.ml#L266
https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/blob/master/src/lib_p2p/p2p_maintenance.ml#L216

Answer (score 0):

It seems that it is currently not possible to ensure the peer stays connected to your private node. See [this](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/278) and [this](https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/367).

So I created a mitigation script to [trust and connect to the private node if it is not connected](https://gist.github.com/gaia/f2aad6d7ea7780775f0079d3ab2f5021).

Comment: Why not just use the tezos-admin-client to add a connection to your private node? Much simpler than restarting the entire node.

Comment: it's a bit more complex than that, `tac connect` isn't behaving as expected https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/issues/547#note_202870810

Comment: but done it with trust then connect